# AWS DMS S3 Endpoint SSE-KMS (InvalidParameterCombinationException)

Tags: amazon-kms, aws-dms

Trying to use Lambda/Boto3 to modify an endpoint.

According to documentation:

```
response = client.modify_endpoint(
    EndpointArn='string',
    S3Settings={
        'EncryptionMode': 'sse-s3'|'sse-kms',
        'ServerSideEncryptionKmsKeyId': 'string',
   }
```

However, when I set 'sse-kms' and pass my KeyID, I am getting this error back :

> [ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred
> (InvalidParameterCombinationException) when calling the ModifyEndpoint
> operation: Only SSE_S3 encryption mode supported. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "/var/task/main.py", line 16, in main
> response = client.modify_endpoint(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

Here's my full Lambda:

```
def main(event,context):
 
    client = boto3.client('dms')

    response = client.modify_endpoint(
        EndpointArn = 'arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:123456789012:endpoint:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ExtraConnectionAttributes = 'cdcPath=undefined',
        S3Settings = {
            'CompressionType': 'none', 
            'DataFormat': 'parquet', 
            'EncryptionMode': 'sse-kms', 
            'ServerSideEncryptionKmsKeyId': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:772631637424:key/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    )
```

Comment: What is the existing EncryptionMode ? Is it the default one or sse-kms ?

Comment: If it is SSE_S3 then you cannot change it to SSE_KMS

Comment: Ok thanks. I was creating the endpoint with Terraform, but lots of bugs there between s3_settings and extra_connection_attributes, seems I can't create this with all the settings I need. Maybe I'll just try creating the entire endpoint with Boto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have created or your existing endpoint EncryptionMode is set to SSE_S3. As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_S3Settings.html) doc it is not possible for you to change from SSE_S3 to SSE_KMS.

***For the ModifyEndpoint operation, you can change the existing value of the EncryptionMode parameter from SSE_KMS to SSE_S3. But you can’t change the existing value from SSE_S3 to SSE_KMS.***